# Vulkan scene object blinking/flickering during transformation using uniform buffer

Tags: synchronization, buffer, vulkan, uniform

I have issue when I transform (e.g. rotate) object (e.g. cube) in the scene using uniform MVP matrix. Rotation is not linear and edges of object are flickering. Watch this https://drive.google.com/open?id=1L1Dx-LUdTdqvCQ23-o-vlI_yQK_t7l2_

1. I use 3 swapchain images/framebuffers/depth buffers, one command
   buffer per each framebuffer. (I have also tried 2,4 and more images)
2. I'have tried to use one uniform buffer for all 3 command buffers and
   separate uniform buffers for each command buffer.
3. Present mode is VK_PRESENT_MODE_IMMEDIATE_KHR (Also I have tried
   FIFO_KHR)
4. Uniform buffers update is synchronized by events in command buffer
   and waiting queue idle in drawing loop that locks mutex for update
   uniform buffer. Data is updated for all uniform buffers
   simultaneously in one function call after drawing loop unlocks mutex
   and command buffer notifies that drawing finished.
5. Command buffers are prepared only once per start program, because
   any data inside is constant (e.g. descriptor set to uniform buffer)
6. uniform buffer is host visible and coherent, mapped during creation
7. main drawing loop executes std operations

   - a) vkAcquireNextImageKHR
   - b) vkWaitForFences for swapchain image
   - c) vkResetFences (b) fence
   - d) vkWaitForFences for previous submitting
   - e) vkResetFences (d) fence
   - f) vkQueueSubmit with previously compilled cmd buffer
   - g) vkQueuePresentKHR
   - h) vkQueueWaitIdle
8. Uniform buffers are updated from main thread by key events.  During
   button press I increment Y angle by 1 degree after that call
   glm::rotate with new angle m_rot_prop.rotation =
   glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::radians(angle.y), glm::vec3(0.f,
   1.0f, 0.f)); Calculate new model m_model = m_rot_prop.rotation*m_trans_prop.transf orm*m_scale_prop.scale;
   After that this data copies by memcpy on uniform buffer pointer.
9. Initially drawing loop and main thread are separate. But I have also
   tried to locate them both to main thread.

I introduced events like this:

1) added the following in command buffer

```
vkBeginCommandBuffer...

vkCmdWaitEvents(cmd_buf, 1, &m_data_update_event[image_number],
VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_HOST_BIT,
VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_VERTEX_SHADER_BIT | VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_HOST_BIT,
0, nullptr,
0, nullptr,
0, nullptr);

vkCmdSetEvent(cmd_buf, m_draw_progress_event[image_number],
VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_ALL_COMMANDS_BIT | VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_ALL_GRAPHICS_BIT);

vkCmdBeginRenderPass....
....
vkCmdEndRenderPass...

vkCmdResetEvent(cmd_buf, m_draw_progress_event[image_number], VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_ALL_COMMANDS_BIT | VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_ALL_GRAPHICS_BIT);
```

2) before update uniform buffer I do

```
m_is_draw_paused = true;
for (uint32_t i = 0; i < m_choosen_swap_chain_details.imagesCount; i++)
{
vkResetEvent(m_logical_device, m_data_update_event[i]);
while (vkGetEventStatus(m_logical_device, m_draw_progress_event[i]) == VK_EVENT_SET)
{
boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::milli seconds(1));
}
}
```

3) update uniform buffer with new MVP matrix (uniform is VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT, VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE)

4) allow rendering

```
for (uint32_t i = 0; i < m_choosen_swap_chain_details.imagesCount; i++)
{
vkSetEvent(m_logical_device, m_data_update_event[i]);
}
```

Could someone know the reason of flickering?

Comment: I see no flickering or blinking in the attached video. You mean the microstutter?

Comment: The video is recorded at 30 FPS, but the FPS counter shows 42. Which in of itself would cause some stutter to be shown.

Comment: VkEvents can be finicky to get right. I would try to do it without them. Spinning on `vkGetEventStatus` is probably a bad idea. Measure if `sleep_for` does not oversleep too much (some platforms can't handle such small naps). Using Fences and QueueWaitIdle is probably overkill for swapchain management. Use Device Local memory explicitly instead of streaming the uniform buffer.

Comment: "microstutter" yes, it can be called like this. But video shows microstutter and big shifts

Comment: >> The video is recorded at 30 FPS, but the FPS counter shows 42. Which in of itself would cause some stutter to be shown. Yes. But actually big lags also are observed and video shows them.

Comment: >>Use Device Local memory explicitly instead of streaming the uniform buffer<< I've tried to use device local memory and copy uniform update from local memory to device each update. But it is very slowly operation and brings more lags.

Comment: last update https://drive.google.com/open?id=1J7KaVd2YTVUZEW1wviguf1Ogd58C7Vwb